# Play framework UUID for model isn't working

Tags: uuid, playframework-1.x

Here is the error I get (using play 1.2.5):

> Compilation error The file /app/models/Fiddle.java could not be
>   compiled. Error raised is : GenericGenerator cannot be resolved to a
>   type

Here is Fiddle.java:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
public class Fiddle extends GenericModel {
    public String html;
    public String css;
    public String js;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid") 
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid") 
    public String id;
```

What is my problem? how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the answer and I had to use this import:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
```

It made some errors with my code so I ended up doing this:

```
@Id 
public String uuid;

// Constractor
public Constructor(String one, String two, String three){
    this.uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID()+"";
```