# Spring boot Auto increment pre-conditioned

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, auto-increment, hibernate-onetomany

How can I set the spring boot jpa to auto-increment @Id  based on specific given values ?
For example, if I want the @Id value starting from (let's say 1000) and increment by (let's say 10) ?

So the first id will be 1000,, the second id will be 1010 ?

My Code as:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long isbn;
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Reader reader;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class Reader {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="reader_id")
    private List<Book> myBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void addBook(Book book) {
        myBooks.add(book);
    }
    
    public void removeBook(Book book) {
        myBooks.remove(book);
    }

}
```

Many Thanxxx

....
Added later:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:713) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:299) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1273) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1262) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.study.SpringBootSpringDataJpaManyToManyJoinQueryCourseStudent1Application.main(SpringBootSpringDataJpaManyToManyJoinQueryCourseStudent1Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1410) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : org.study.entity.Course
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:612) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    GenericGenerator cannot be resolved to a type
    Parameter cannot be resolved to a type
    Parameter cannot be resolved to a type
    Parameter cannot be resolved to a type

    at org.study.entity.Course.<init>(Course.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

I got this error message ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the sequence generator as per the example below:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "sequence-generator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "reader_sequence"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1000"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "10")
        }
)
private Long id;
```

Comment: how to post it here !

Comment: @AdelLinuix80s You can edit your answer and attach the error stacktrace there

Comment: I edited the question and added the error message above :)

Comment: For the error I think a similar one is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18032170/3635454. Check the import of import of `GenericGenerator` in your classes. Plus it looks like it needs a constructor with 3 parameters.

Comment: lombok data annotation is placed in the main code.. It has all constructor & no constructor ,,, why we would we need a three parameter constructor.. it is there!

Comment: I am not aware of this error, prior posting my answer I did a quick *working* example based on spring-boot `2.5.4` (stable) and I posted the answer's code. In your stacktrace I notice that you use spring-boot version `2.6.0-SNAPSHOT`, which is one nightly build. This version is not stable and may introduce errors or bugs, why you chose this version and not the stable one? I suggest you to switch to spring-boot `2.5.4` and clean build your project.

Comment: I switched to spring-boot 2.5.4 and rebuilt the project....  I got the same result! the initial value was still starting from 1 even though the error message disappeared